# Same html code, the same id/class applied - but they show in a different way

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at [this page](http://glamourina.pl/media-o-mnie/).
As you can see in central column, on the left site `<div class="fLeft">` there are some links.

Problem: the text inside the `<div class="fLeft">` has a different style from the Company name with `<a id="modaija"...`

Before this part of the code the font has a higher weight and has the first letter big.

I cannot find a reasonable explanation, because both the `<div class="fLeft">` where there are two different styles have the same structure. Here it is:

```
<div class="post_blog">
<div class="entry_blog">
<div class="wrapperblogi">
<div class="col2">
<div class="fLeft">
<div style="margin-top:65px">
<p>and the texts are here inside</p>
```

I have checked also the links themselves. They do not have any ID or CLASS applied or element.style applied.

I have checked with the Chrome dev tool and it seems that the CSS is the same.
However for the links with bolder text and big first letter it shows me the properties for: `.entry_blog a`whereas for the below links with a different style it shows me properties for just `a`.

I can't really understand why there is a different style applied to the two parts of code.
They have been coded in the same way. In order to add new links I just copied and pasted the codes of the `<div class="wrapperblogi">` above, and so always.

To be clear... the right code is the one above... the one that changes color on :hover. It doesn't look well there, I'll change that, but before making changes I prefer to understand what's wrong and correct it.

I can add that the W3C validator doesn't show any errors for that code. Only some not important errors in the header or footer.

Is there anything wrong somewhere?

Comment: Are you not missing a closing tag somewhere? Or have an extra one?

Comment: I think not. I went through all the code and I didn't find anything. But maybe I missed out something

Comment: interesting why I got a -1

Answer (score 0):

It is because they are surrounded by `<strong></strong>` tags

Comment: I don't see any `<strong></strong>` tags in styl.fm compared to modaija. And the `<strong></strong>` tags do not change the first letter of the paragraphs.

Comment: because it isn't in style it is placed in the html

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of the problem. There were 3 closing `</div>` in a row before:

```
      </div>

</div>

</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<!-- end -->

<br />

&nbsp;<br />

<div class="wrapperblogi" >

  <div class="col2">

    <div class="companyname"><a id="modaija..."
```

But there should be only two. When I deleted the 3rd one, the code works fine. It now looks like this:

```
     </div>

</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<!-- end -->

<br /> ...
```